# SQL Query - Determine who has only one gift record

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I would like to know how I can write a SQL Script so a within a group of individuals initially selected:

```
SELECT  [RECORDS].[CONSTITUENT_ID]
  ,[RECORDS].[FIRST_NAME]
  ,[RECORDS].[LAST_NAME]
  ,[DATEADDED]
  ,[DTE]
  ,[Amount]
  ,[REF]
  ,[TYPE]
 FROM [re7].[dbo].[GIFT]
 INNER JOIN [re7].[dbo].[RECORDS]
 ON GIFT.CONSTIT_ID LIKE RECORDS.ID
 WHERE ([DTE] BETWEEN '2/7/2015' AND '2/8/2015') 
 ORDER BY [DATEADDED] DESC
```

select only individuals who are "First Time Donors" (or someone who only has one gift in [re7].[dbo].[GIFT].

[RECORDS] is a table of all the constituents.

[GIFT] is a table of all recorded Gifts.

The output of the above Query, is just a table with:
CONSTITUENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATEADDED, DTE, Amount, REF, TYPE

I pretty much want to see the same output format, but I would like the query to select only CONSTITUENT_ID who only have 1 GIFT (by their Record ID) in [re7].[dbo].[GIFT].

I apologize for the lack of data to show. I wish I could describe better....

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: why are you using like in this way `ON GIFT.CONSTIT_ID LIKE RECORDS.ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  [RECORDS].[CONSTITUENT_ID]
  ,[RECORDS].[FIRST_NAME]
  ,[RECORDS].[LAST_NAME]
  ,[DATEADDED]
  ,[DTE]
  ,[Amount]
  ,[REF]
  ,[TYPE]
 FROM [re7].[dbo].[GIFT]
 INNER JOIN [re7].[dbo].[RECORDS]
 ON GIFT.CONSTIT_ID LIKE RECORDS.ID
 WHERE ([DTE] BETWEEN '2/7/2015' AND '2/8/2015')
     AND GIFT.CONSTIT_ID IN (
         SELECT CONSTIT_ID FROM re7.dbo.Gift GROUP BY CONSTIT_ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
     ) /* another option is to add a subquery to the query you already had */
 ORDER BY [DATEADDED] DESC
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the other answer. It is slightly easier to incorporate into an existing query though.

Answer (score 0):

This solution simply selects all the constituents who have made only one donation and then joins to that, thereby limiting the result set.

```
SELECT  
    r.[CONSTITUENT_ID]
    ,r.[FIRST_NAME]
    ,r.[LAST_NAME]
    ,[DATEADDED]
    ,[DTE]
    ,[Amount]
    ,[REF]
    ,[TYPE]
FROM 
    (select [CONSTIT_ID] from [re7].[dbo].[GIFT] group by [CONSTIT_ID] having count([CONSTIT_ID]) = 1) g1
    inner join [re7].[dbo].[GIFT] g
        on g.[CONSTIT_ID] = g1.[CONSTIT_ID]
    INNER JOIN [re7].[dbo].[RECORDS] r
        ON g.CONSTIT_ID LIKE r.RECORDS.ID
WHERE ([DTE] BETWEEN '2/7/2015' AND '2/8/2015') 
ORDER BY [DATEADDED] DESC
```